# SFTP is not successfully connecting to some clients, error is returned

Tags: centos, ssh, sftp

I have an SFTP server installed on Centos 8. First, I created a group sftpusers and users (with passwords) in it. I added following lines in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file:

```
Port 22
Port 33000
...
#Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
...
#At the end of the file:
Match LocalPort 33000 Group sftpusers Address *
    ChrootDirectory /home/sftp
    ClientAliveInterval 300
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowGroups sftpusers
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Then I used: `systemctl restart sshd.service`. Also, command `semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 33000` is needed. But when I use the command `sftp -P 33000 -vvv user@host` to connect from my PC I receive an error that ends with

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection timed out

Connection closed
```

I want to enable a connection with passwords, not keys. From some other servers I successfully connected to the SFTP server, but from some (Windows 10, Linux, FileZilla, command line) not.